# Java - make class required for other class

Tags: java

i have 2 class, planet and moon, my plan is to make moon class require planet class, so first i create planet and then create moon, how to do it?
my planet class :

```
public class planet {
    //planet name
    private String namaPlanet;
    //total moon per planet
    private int jmlBulan;
    //revolution and rotation
    private double jmlRotasi, jmlRevolusi;
public planet(String namaPlanet, int jmlBulan, double jmlJamPhari, double jmlHariPtahun) {
    this.namaPlanet = namaPlanet;
    this.jmlBulan = jmlBulan;
    this.jmlRotasi = jmlJamPhari;
    this.jmlRevolusi = jmlHariPtahun;
}

public planet(String namaPlanet, double jmlRotasi, double jmlRevolusi) {
    this.namaPlanet = namaPlanet;
    this.jmlRotasi = jmlRotasi;
    this.jmlRevolusi = jmlRevolusi;
}
}
```

moon class :

```
public class bulan extends planet {
private String namaBulan;
public bulan(String namaBulan, String namaPlanet,double jmlJamPhari, double jmlHariPtahun) {
    super(namaPlanet, jmlJamPhari, jmlHariPtahun);
    this.namaBulan = namaBulan;
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear - what is the actual problem here?

Comment: `Moon` extends `planet`, so plantet will be "created" if moon is created

Comment: Read about inheritance OOP concept, May be it will help you. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Comment: Unrelated, I'd advise you to stick with the [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) to make it easier for people to read your code.

Comment: More related, by making Moon extend Planet, you're expressing that a Moon is a Planet, while it'd be more accurate to say that a Planet can have zero or more Moons...  The tutorial @Dharani linked to explains that in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a moon *is not* a planet you should not derive your Moon class from Planet, but rather give moon a reference to a planet and/or let planet have a list of moons.

```
public class Moon {
    private String name;
    private Planet planet;

    public Moon(String name, Planet planet) {
         this.name = name;
         this.planet = planet;
    }
}
```